# How Javascript functions run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering how javascript functions load or run.

Take for example i have got these block of javascripts functions;

```
<span id=indicator></span>

function BlockOne(){
    var textToWrite = document.createTextNode("I am   ");
    document.getElementById("indicator").appendChild(textToWrite);
} 
//==========
function BlockTwo(){
    var textToWrite = document.createTextNode("Going   ");
    document.getElementById("indicator").appendChild(textToWrite);
} 
//=========
function BlockThree(){
    var textToWrite = document.createTextNode("To School   ");
    document.getElementById("indicator").appendChild(textToWrite);
} 

function RunAll(){
    BlockOne();
    BlockTwo();
    BlockThree();
}
window.onload=RunAll();
```

Please which of these block of function run first or in what order are they going to run.

Comment: In the first example `BlockThree` will run but none of the others

Comment: Pretty sure they run sequentially, and you forgot to add `()` to the end of each function.

Comment: `window.onload=BlockOne=BlockTwo=BlockThree;` <-- does not do what you think it does.

Comment: You should consider using `window.addEventListener("load", yourFunction, false)` instead of `window.onload = yourFunction` unless you need to support old browsers.

Comment: @epascarello so what about if we have a declaration of variables say  var d=a=c=e=" ";

Comment: @Simlofi that `var` statement declares just **one** variable - `d`.

Comment: @Pointy no i dis agreed var d=" ", a=" ", c="", e=" "; should mean the same thing with var d=a=c=e=" ";

Comment: @Simlofi Try it out for yourself!  It **definitely** does not mean the same thing.

Comment: i have tested it it mean the same thing let me create a jsfiddle for you to verify.

Comment: @Pointy  var d=a=c=b="thanks";

alert(b);     https://jsfiddle.net/t855kssa/

Comment: @Simlofi you're creating **global** variables, not local ones. I'll set up a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Simlofi http://jsfiddle.net/6sqqye4b/ - the problem is that everything after the first `=` is part of the initialization expression. The `var` statement only declares the first variable to the **left** of the first `=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
window.onload=BlockOne=BlockTwo=BlockThree;
```

will result in only "BlockThree" running when the "load" event fires. The way that assignment statement is interpreted is as if it were written:

```
window.onload = (BlockOne = (BlockTwo = BlockThree));
```

The right-most `=` operator causes the symbol "BlockTwo" to be set to the same value as "BlockThree", and then the middle `=` assigns that value (still "BlockThree") to "BlockOne".  Function definition statements bind the function name to a local symbol, but they're not special symbols; they're pretty much the same as ordinary `var` symbols.

When that's all done, the "onload" property of `window` is set to just one function reference, and that's "BlockThree".  After that point the original functions associated with "BlockOne" and "BlockTwo" will no longer be referenceable; they're essentially gone.

The second will run none of them, because your "RunAll" function is missing the function call operator ( `()` ) for all three of the functions. If it were

```
function RunAll(){
  BlockOne();BlockTwo();BlockThree();
}
```

then all three would run, in the order listed left-to-right.

Comment: You should explain that in the first example, you are assigning `window.onload = BlockThree; BlockOne = BlockThree; BlockTwo = BlockThree`

Comment: @soktinpk working on it - I was just having a sneezing fit :)

Comment: @Pointy so they run from up to down or from bottom to up

Comment: @Simlofi the order in which the functions are *declared* does not matter at all. What matters is the order in which the functions are **called**.

Comment: @Pointy still you have not answered my question but I appreciate your answer what i am asking is for any reason which one trigger first

Comment: @Pointy can see I am trying to write I am Going To School, so what about if  i put "To school" in block 2 . Note this may result in writting "I am To School Going"